# PHP is sending null values to MySql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using PHPStorm and I am trying to send my user's input from an html form to my database using PHP. My database seems to be getting the inputs since it creates a new id (which is the primary key and it is set to auto-increment) however, the fields are empty!

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="i_createaccount" id="createaccount" action="info.php" method="post">
        <h2 class="formtitle">Create an account</h2>
        <input type="text" class="firstnlast" name="i_name" placeholder="First Name" required/>
        <input type="text" class="firstnlast" name="i_last" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
        <input id="txtEmail" type="email" name="i_email" placeholder="Email" required/>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="next, button" value="Join Now"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my info.php

```
<?php

if(empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) {
    $type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] = $type;
}
//Connecting to sql db.


    define('DB_NAME', 'nabi_data');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Cant use ' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
    }
$message = '';

    $i_name = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'i_name');
    $i_last = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'i_last');
    $i_email = (string)filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'i_email');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO nabi_instructors (i_name, i_last, i_email) VALUES ('$i_name', '$i_last', '$i_email')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());


        mysql_close();
    }
```

Comment: use a conditional `!empty()` for your POST arrays.

Comment: Please switch to PDO or mysqli instead of using mysql_* functions. Those functions have been deprecated, and removed as of PHP7.

Comment: provide your table structure as well.

Comment: Hi CodeGodie! I do not know how to attach a pictrue to this comment section, my database is full of rows with an id but missing the name, last name and email.